# Not using SQL Transactions

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am looking at a codebase where a developer never uses SQL transactions i.e. each update/insert into the SQL database is an atomic operation.

I believe the codebase would benefit from transactions.  I was looking online today and in one Stackoverflow question an answerer says: "In some situations it is better to have a partial update rather than none at all".  Is there any truth in this? I suppose it depends on the problem domain to some extent.

Comment: What is it doing? A partial update in finance is likely much worse than none.  A partial update to a log file is likely 'ho hum'.

Comment: There are no Transactions.  I was taught that if an operation inserts/updates two or more tables then it should be part of a Transaction.  I am wandering if there are scenarios when this statement is false.

Comment: @MichaelT,it is a high volume website.  This article seems to hold true: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html

Comment: I have worked on high volume finance web sites, and high volume bug tracking web sites.  On the bug tracking, I had auto commit turned on - this was for ease of use more than performance.  In finance, it was all transactions that reflected one consistent set of state changes.

Comment: @MichaelT, thanks +1.  Can you post an answer so that I can give credit?

Comment: @w0051977 Distributed systems have their own issues, of course. Maintaining a transaction across such a system is a complex task.

Answer (score 11):

It depends not just on the problem domain, but also on technical considerations. Basically, it comes down to the simple question: "Will there be unacceptable problems when a partial update happens?" Some examples:

- Transfering money from one account to another. A partial update is completely unacceptable for domain reasons.
- Adding a vote to an online poll and incrementing a result count (which is only for display, with the final result being recalculated from the vote table). A partial update is probably acceptable.
- Adding something to an n:m relationship. A partial update would result in an inconsistent state where you have either an entry that is not connected, or a connection without a matching entry. This is unacceptable for technical reasons - you'd get an error whenever that entry is encountered and it would likely be impossible to fix this error within the system.
- A hardware unit that sends batches of sensor data to be stored. Adding only some of the entries of a batch is probably better than losing all of it.

Honestly, it's really rare for partial updates to be tolerable.

Comment: Thanks +1.  What are your thoughts on this article? martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html

Comment: @w0051977: The key statement is "You have to pay attention to the order of your commits, getting the more important ones in first. At each commit you have to check that it succeeded and decide what to do if it fails." - that's quite a lot of additional work compared to using transactions, and very error-prone. You're manually doing something very similar to what a DB does when you use transactions. But it's hand-tailored for every single operation, which allows you to do only the minimal work necessary to maintain exactly as much integrity as you need.

Answer (score 0):

From the database perspective, frequent commits are often used to prevent records being unreadable by other sessions as they are locked by the updating session.

However this varies by RDBMS. Oracle has always had an MVCC system that prevented readers from blocking writers and writers from blocking readers, so it is not a problem there for instance.

Over-frequent committing on Oracle is strongly discouraged not only because it can leave partial transactions in the system but also because a COMMIT requires a synchronous redo log buffer flush which stalls the session (a high level of log_file_sync wait events is symptomatic of over-committing). Redo log buffers are asynchronously flushed every few seconds or when they are X% full anyway, so a longer running transaction may have less work to do during an explicit commit if it is deferred until the end of the business transaction anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure how this answers my question.  Are you saying it is acceptable not to use transactions in high volume websites? What is a high volume website? I understand it to mean a website that is a front end to a database containing lots of records but I am unsure.

Comment: What I'm saying is that one consideration in deciding whether to commit frequently is the database technology. On some, for example Oracle, frequent commits will be slower. On others frequent commits are required to avoid locking problems. what database is used for the system you are using?

Comment: Thanks.  The system in question queries multiple systems (using SELECT), but only updates/deletes/inserts from/into one SQL Server database.

Comment: The use of SQL Server may explain why frequent commits are issued.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify why it may explain why frequent commits are issued? +1.

Comment: SQL Server is one of the systems in which a modified record is locked and cannot be viewed by other sessions by default.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that Transactions are not as important in SQL Server?

Comment: No, I'm saying that limitations in handling changed records cause SQL Server developers to commit more frequently than they should.

Comment: Thanks.  Finally, do you know what is meant by "high volume sites" in the following links: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html.  I am wandering if this is referring to the number of users or the amount of information.